# Using mod_rewrite to mask /cgi-bin/abc as /def

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, mod-rewrite

I have a seemingly easy task, but somehow I just can't get it to work:

Some interesting lines from my httpd.conf:

```
...
DocumentRoot "D:/opt/apache/htdocs"
...
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "D:/opt/apache/cgi-bin/"
...
<Directory "D:/opt/apache/htdocs">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "D:/opt/apache/cgi-bin/">
    AllowOverride None
    Options ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

(I know it's dumb but it's only a testing machine :D.)

Now, I have `d:\opt\apache\cgi-bin\expired.pl` and I expect `GET /licensecheck.php?code=123456`.  And I wish to fake client into thinking it speaks with `/licensecheck.php`, but actually return data by `\expired.pl`.

What I tried was setting following at the end of `http.conf`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/licensecheck.php$ /cgi-bin/expired.pl [T=application/x-httpd-cgi,L]
```

...but it keeps 404-ing me, looking for cgi-bin *directory* (not cgi-bin\expired.pl) in my DocumentRoot!

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] script not found or unable to stat: D:/opt/apache/htdocs/cgi-bin
```

- /cgi-bin/expired.pl and all other scripts in /cgi-bin/ work as expected,
- Only way I could make it work was actually putting the `\expired.pl` to DocumentRoot, but I don't want this, I want my cgi-bin neatly separated :)

Comment: 1. Do you have a Directory directive for "D:/opt/apache/cgi-bin/" with permission set correctly? 2. Where did you put the `RewriteEngine on` et alli?

Comment: Try `[PT]` flag: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt

Comment: @ChrisS: Updated according to your questions

Comment: @LazyOne: Thanks, that actually works!  Seems that I misunderstood mod_rewrite--i thought that *was* taken as URI. Thanks again all yoou guys!

Comment: @AloisMahdal Please answer to your question, and check it as "Ok".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was just a misunderstanding; I thought that the subject for rewrite is implicitly taken as URI.

Adding `[PT]` changed the behavior, which solved my problem:

```
RewriteRule ^/licensecheck.php$ /cgi-bin/pct-expired.pl [T=application/x-httpd-cgi,L,PT]
```